# AWS LexV2 CDK/CloudFormation error when using Image Response Cards

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-lex

I am deploying a Lex V2 bot with AWS CDK and want my bot to have buttons for eliciting slots, but for some reason I get an error:

```sh
DevBot Resource handler returned message: 

"Importing CDK-DevBot failed due to [There was an error importing the bot. 
Make sure that the imported bot and contents of the zip file are correct, then try your request again.]. 
The import could not be completed." 

(RequestToken: ebd3354f-6169-922a-d0f9-d14690671e25, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

This error is not very informative. The relevant part of the `CloudFormation` template: ["Message"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lex-bot-message.html)

```json
"MessageGroupsList: [{
  "Message": {
    "ImageResponseCard": {
      "Buttons": [
        {
          "Text": "1.0.3",
          "Value": "1.0.3"
        },
        {
          "Text": "1.0.5",
          "Value": "1.0.5"
        }
      ],
      "Title": "Title"
    },
    "PlainTextMessage": {
      "Value": "Please enter the issue number"
    }
  }
}]
```

If I remove `"ImageResponseCard"` then it deploys okay. Otherwise, I get the error.

Has anybody else had this problem and found a way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MessageGroupList` is an array of `Message` elements. Every element must have a different type of Message that could be `ImageResponseCard` or `PlainTextMessage`. So in your case the template has an incorrect structure, it should be something like that:

```
{
    "MessageGroupsList": [
        {
            "Message": {
                "ImageResponseCard": {
                    "Buttons": [
                        {
                            "Text": "1.0.3",
                            "Value": "1.0.3"
                        },
                        {
                            "Text": "1.0.5",
                            "Value": "1.0.5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Title": "Title"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Message": {
                "PlainTextMessage": {
                    "Value": "Please enter the issue number"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Assumming that the missing tick in `MessageGroupList` is a typo.